# What are these big Zeiss lenses?

Tags: lens, canon, zeiss

I'm not sure how to ask this other than "What are these big lenses?"

One of the comments mentions that they might be Zeiss. I'm not sure how to tell.

[image]

Comment: They are "*telephoto*" lenses, a named reserved for "long" focal lengths.  The long focal length generally requires the lens itself to be long, hence the big barrels you see.

Comment: @OlinLathrop "telephoto" is not reserved for long focal lengths, but for lenses whose front principal plane lies outside the lens body. The lens on the right is a short focal length T1.3 prime (accounting for the size) which is the very opposite of a telephoto, being a retrofocal design!

Comment: Oh i recognize those,  they are MONEY.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They're both Cine lenses mounted on Canon 1DCs. The 1DC is a variant of Canon's 1DX flagship DSLR, which can shoot 4K video using the central APS-H region of the 35mm sensor.

The one on the left is an Angenieux Optimo 12x, a very high end 24-290mm T2.8 cine superzoom lens:

[image]
<sub>(source: [gulfcamera.com](http://gulfcamera.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/24-290.jpg))</sub>

The one on the right is a Zeiss master series T1.3 prime lens, probably the 12mm:

http://www.servicevision.es/sites/default/files/imagecache/news-inside/noticias/imagenes/imagen11.jpg

The T1.3 specification accounts for the size of the lens - T1.3 means a t-stop of 1.3, sort of like a f-stop but based on the measured transmission of light, not the aperture size alone. A T1.3 lens is most likely f/1.2!

I'm afraid you can't afford either of them ;)

Comment: +1 for the understatement of the year "I'm afraid you can't afford either of them"

Comment: Ha! Ditto - +1 from me too :-)

Comment: lol. but the Zeiss is listed for *only* $25,000 on ebay!

Comment: Actually I dislike comments like this. I know it's being said in jest, but you do not know what someone can afford, and personally I find this kind of financial judgement to be a little insulting.

Comment: @osullic I disagree, precisely *because* it is unknown what the OP can afford; in this case, the statement does not have the power to offend. It is, after all, a sure bet that *most* people reading this cannot afford either lens. (Though quite a number of people could probably cough up $25,000 if sufficiently motivated. It's not more than a car, after all.)